# Yii2: How to show checked values in CheckboxList

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I want to show checked values in my checkboxlist in Yii 2.0. Following is my code:

**Main Array:**

```
<?php
$featureArr = array(
    'Change Requester' => 'Change Requester',
    'Clone Request' => 'Clone Request',
    'Suspend Request' => 'Suspend Request',
    'In-Process Requests Open in Edit Mode' => 'In-Process Requests Open in Edit Mode',
    'Allow On-the-Fly Notifications' => 'Allow On-the-Fly Notifications',
    'Additional Comments Field' => 'Additional Comments Field',
    'Do Not Validate Draft Requests' => 'Do Not Validate Draft Requests',
    '(Web-Only) Allow File Attachments' => '(Web-Only) Allow File Attachments',
);
```

**Getting data from table to display checked items:**

```
$formFeatureModel = FormFeatureForm::find()->where("form_id=" . $model->id)->all();

$checkedFeatureArr = array();
foreach ($formFeatureModel as $data) {
    $checkedFeatureArr[$data->feature] = $data->feature;
}
?>
```

**Checkbox field**

```
<?= $form->field(new FormFeatureForm, 'feature')->checkboxList($featureArr, ['class' => 'featureCls']) ?>
```

I am getting checked item in `$checkedFeatureArr` from database. Now I just want to show checked items. So, Where should I pass `$checkedFeatureArr` array? Getting stuck in this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using it with model, you should fill `feature` model property with selected values instead.

```
$model->feature = $checkedFeatureArr;
```

Then it will be checked automatically.

**Additional tips:**

- It's better avoid concatenation in SQL, replace `->where("form_id=" . $model->id)` with `->where(['form_id' => $model->id])`.
- It's better create `ActiveForm` before rendering `ActiveField`.

Comment: Thanks.. It was quite easy.. :) and Thanks for suggestion.