# Yii2 checkboxList check checked value

Tags: php, checkbox, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

My demo code is given below. My method returns data from database and on that value how i show it checked or not

```
<?php
$notf_col = [
    "1" => 'User Create',
    "2" => 'User Update',
];

$check_data = NotificationChecklist::getCheckList(Yii::$app->user->identity->id);
//check data will hold ["1","2"]
if (!empty($check_data)) {
    $checkedList = $check_data; //get selected value from db if value exist
    $model->notf_action_col = $checkedList;
}
?>

<div class="notification-checklist-form">
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' => 'notification-checklist/create',]); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'notf_action_col')->checkboxList($notf_col)->label(FALSE) ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `$model->$notf_col = $checkedList;` to `$model->notf_col = $checkedList;` and check.

Comment: And, do like this. `$model->notf_action_col = $checkedList;<?= $form->field($model, 'notf_action_col')->checkboxList($notf_col)->label(FALSE) ?>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2: How to show checked values in CheckboxList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888665/yii2-how-to-show-checked-values-in-checkboxlist)

Comment: i try to follow that question but it doesn't working that's why i posted it here

Comment: try with: $model->notf_action_col = true, but pay attention, only in if is new post

Comment: Please try to pay attention I need to update specific column not full table and for that reason I am doing a query and check that not empty?

Comment: what is your `$check_data` output ?

Comment: its a array ["1", "2"]

Comment: Problem solved, here problem is it was json object looks like a array but when i decode it and general array format then it works fine thanks all